# Cannot import pipeline after successful transformers installation

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

### Environment info

- `transformers` version: 4.9.0
- Platform: Linux-4.15.0-151-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.27
- Python version: 3.9.2
- PyTorch version (GPU?): 1.7.1+cu101 (False)
- Tensorflow version (GPU?): 2.5.0 (False)
- Flax version (CPU?/GPU?/TPU?): 0.3.4 (cpu)
- Jax version: 0.2.17
- JaxLib version: 0.1.69
- Using GPU in script?: no
- Using distributed or parallel set-up in script?: no

### Details

I am attempting to use a fresh installation of transformers library, but after successfully completing the installation with pip, I am not able to run the test script: `python -c "from transformers import pipeline; print(pipeline('sentiment-analysis')('we love you'))"`

Instead, I see the following output:

> /home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/similarities/**init**.py:15: UserWarning: The gensim.similarities.levenshtein submodule is disabled, because the optional Levenshtein package <https://pypi.org/proje$
> t/python-Levenshtein/> is unavailable. Install Levenhstein (e.g. `pip install python-Levenshtein`) to suppress this warning.
> warnings.warn(msg)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py", line 1977, in **getattr**
> module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py", line 1986, in _get_module
> return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.**name**)
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/**init**.py", line 25, in 
> from ..models.auto.configuration_auto import AutoConfig
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/**init**.py", line 19, in 
> from . import (
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/layoutlm/**init**.py", line 22, in 
> from .configuration_layoutlm import LAYOUTLM_PRETRAINED_CONFIG_ARCHIVE_MAP, LayoutLMConfig
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/layoutlm/configuration_layoutlm.py", line 19, in 
> from ..bert.configuration_bert import BertConfig
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/configuration_bert.py", line 21, in 
> from ...onnx import OnnxConfig
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/onnx/**init**.py", line 16, in 
> from .config import EXTERNAL_DATA_FORMAT_SIZE_LIMIT, OnnxConfig, OnnxConfigWithPast
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/onnx/config.py", line 18, in 
> from transformers import PretrainedConfig, PreTrainedTokenizer, TensorType
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py", line 1977, in **getattr**
> module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py", line 1986, in _get_module
> return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.**name**)
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils.py", line 26, in 
> from .tokenization_utils_base import (
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 74, in 
> from tokenizers import AddedToken
> File "/home/shushan/tokenization_experiments/tokenizers.py", line 26, in 
> from transformers import BertTokenizer
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py", line 1978, in **getattr**
> value = getattr(module, name)
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py", line 1977, in **getattr**
> module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py", line 1986, in _get_module
> return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.**name**)
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> File "/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/tokenization_bert.py", line 23, in 
> from ...tokenization_utils import PreTrainedTokenizer, _is_control, _is_punctuation, _is_whitespace
> ImportError: cannot import name 'PreTrainedTokenizer' from partially initialized module 'transformers.tokenization_utils' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/shushan/.conda/envs/ccg_parser/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformer
> s/tokenization_utils.py)

I have attempted uninstalling transformers and re-installing them, but I couldn't find any more information as to what is wrong, or how to go about fixing this issue I am seeing. The only suspicious behavior is that the output of `transformers-cli env` command above specifies the pytorch version does not work with GPU, while in reality, I have an installation of pytorch that works with gpu. Can you help?
Thanks in advance
Shushan

Answer (score 1):

Maybe presence of both Pytorch and TensorFlow or maybe incorrect creation of the environment is causing the issue. Try re-creating the environment while installing bare minimum packages and just keep one of Pytorch or TensorFlow.

It worked perfectly fine for me with the following config:

```
 - transformers version: 4.9.0
 - Platform: macOS-10.14.6-x86_64-i386-64bit
 - Python version: 3.9.2 
 - PyTorch version (GPU?): 1.7.1 (False) 
 - Tensorflow version (GPU?): not installed (NA) 
 - Flax version (CPU?/GPU?/TPU?): not installed (NA) 
 - Jax version: not installed 
 - JaxLib version: not installed 
 - Using GPU in script?: <fill in> 
 - Using distributed or parallel set-up in script?: <fill in>
```